# ES6 import not working when exposed via index.js

Tags: javascript

I am having this weird issue. I have an index file like:

```
// index.js
import * as constants from './constants';

export {
  constants,
  ...
};

// constants.js
const CUSTOMER_CREATE_SUCCESS_KAFKA_PAYLOAD = '...';
const CUSTOMER_CREATE_ERROR_KAFKA_PAYLOAD = '...';
const ACCOUNT_CREATE_SUCCESS_KAFKA_PAYLOAD = '...';
const ACCOUNT_CREATE_ERROR_KAFKA_PAYLOAD = '...';

const ValidationSchemas = {
  CUSTOMER_CREATE_SUCCESS_KAFKA_PAYLOAD,
  CUSTOMER_CREATE_ERROR_KAFKA_PAYLOAD,
  ACCOUNT_CREATE_SUCCESS_KAFKA_PAYLOAD,
  ACCOUNT_CREATE_ERROR_KAFKA_PAYLOAD,
};

export {
  ValidationSchemas,
}
```

I can use the constants file when I access it directly,

```
// consumers/handler.js
import * as constants from '../constants';
const { ValidationSchemas } = constants;
```

But when I do

```
import { constants } from '..'; // trying to access via index.js
const { ValidationSchemas } = constants;
```

I get

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'ValidationSchemas' of '_.constants' as it is undefined.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/data/...)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Module._compile (/data/...)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: @Sirko `import { constants } from …` does not do destructuring. And `export { constants }` does create an export named `constants` in *index.js*.

Comment: Are you using a transpiler? Do you have circular dependencies? Can you post a minimal example of files necessary to reproduce this? Are you sure you're importing the right file?

Comment: Yes babel is used. Let me try an example

Comment: @Bergi found the issue ... you are right, circular dependency